# Vertically Align a Span within a TD

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into some troubles with CSS formatting of table columns with bootstrap. A normal `td` looks like this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 10px;">
<span class="edit-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="vertical-align: top !important;"></span>
Content
</td>
```

With the `edit-icon` class looking like:

```
.edit-icon {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

Ideally, the content in the cell should be centered vertically and the icon should be in the top right corner. I've tried for hours, but to no avail, to figure out how to align one element to the middle vertically and one element to the top vertically in the same cell.

To help further display the problem, here is the current look:

[image: Bad Version]

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image: Desired Version]

Any help with how to solve this CSS conundrum would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the link. You missed it

Comment: This site is not yet online. Let me know if you are in need of any other particular element of the code and I will be happy to provide it to you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Single cell**

One way to do this is to make the span position absolute. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWRvG/3/)**.

The changes are (the height and width are just for demonstration):

CSS:

```
table
{
    position:relative;        
}
td
{    
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:grey;          
}
span
{
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
   <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 10px;">
      <span class="edit-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span>
      Content
   </td>
</table>
```

The table position is relative, so that this is the position that the span will base its absolute position from.

**Multiple Cells**

Now, the only problem with that is that it doesn't work so well when you have multiple table cells because the image will always be using the table for the offset point. So, you need to make the position relative to the `td`. However, this is not simple. See [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/) for a way to do this. Essentially it involves putting another div inside the td that fills the td and then using that for the position. Also, you want to preserve center text. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) for a discussion on centering vertically. Another approach is to set the table cell to position to `block`. However, if you do that then you lose the vertical centering of the text. A nice solution is to use a transform (note the supported browsers on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)).

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWRvG/5/)** shows it working for multiple table cells. Basically: -

- `td` `display:block` means that it can be the relative point.
- `.content` wraps the text that needs to be centered vertically.
- `transform` shifts the content up by half its height from the center of the `td`, so it is in the middle.

CSS:

```
td
{ 
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:grey;       
}

span
{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;    
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;    
}

.content
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 10px;">            
                <span class="edit-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Content</p>
                <p>More content</p>
                <p>Even more content</p>
                <p>So much more content</p>            
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 10px;">            
                <span class="edit-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Content</p>
                <p>More content</p>
                <p>Even more content</p>
                <p>So much more content</p>            
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ruddy - no, the content is still center aligned, as per the request.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. In that case yes that's what I would do. +1.

Comment: Making the `table` have `position: relative;` caused the icon to display to the top right outside of the table. However, when I made each `td` relative, instead, the correct style was rendered - thank you for the help!

Comment: @mattkgross - See my update. If you have multiple table cells then my single-cell answer would position relative to the table rather than the cell. I am surprised it worked for you when you set td to position relative, since td normally can't take position relative unless displayed as a block. Maybe it is something to do with using bootstrap?

Comment: I am guessing it is most likely a bootstrap issue. At least it is solved now, though. Thanks again!